# How can i combine two formulas in formula bar in powerapps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection, powerapps-modeldriven

I need to apply two formulas on a dropdown field. How to apply both the formulas?I want to use the distinct funciton to avoid the duplicate values & the dropdown values depend on another column values. I have the formulas in hand but dont know how to apply both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just chain them like in most other languages `fn1(fn2(x))`.
Not knowing the second function i'll just assume it to be filter:

```
Distinct(Filter(MyTableVariable, MyFilterColumn = "MyFilterCriteria"), MyReturnValuesColumn)
```

an additional note: this code goes into the Items property of the dropdown

Comment: Distinct(Energy_Facilities,City) this is the first formula &  Filter(Energy_Facilities, Country = DataCardValue8.Selected.Result) this is the second

Comment: simply nesting them like the example should do the trick: Distinct(Filter(Energy_Facilities, Country = DataCardValue8.Selected.Result), City)

Comment: will need more details. where are you trying to use that function? on a second dropdown? what error are you getting?

Comment: That worked for me. it was my small mistake. Thanks a lot sir